# Alternative to jquery tmpl for inline html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am currently running into long inline html in my jquery in order to generate long html snippets on the fly.
Example:

```
var personalMessage = $("<div title='" + chatid + "' class='personalMessage'><div class='personalChatName'>" + fullname + "</div><div class='personalChatDialog'></div></div>")
$ContactsBar.prepend(personalMessage);
```

I want to add even more html in my `personalMessage` so i started to think that jquery.tmpl will be perfect for this, but jQuery discontinued it which i dont know why, but is there something new or an alternative that everyone uses now thats better? or is everyone still just using jquery.tmpl?

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585573/html-templates-in-javascript-without-coding-in-the-page

Comment: I like [jsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) for templating, but it's still not even in Beta status, so there could still be breaking changes as development continues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i came across this one just recently: [t.js](https://github.com/jasonmoo/t.js)

however, if your needs are fairly limited you could just extend `String` with a simple `template` function:

```
String.prototype.template = function(obj) {
    return this.replace(/\{\{([\w]+)\}\}/g, function(str, prop) {
        return obj[prop];
    });
};

alert('<div>my name is: {{last}}, {{first}}</div>'.template({first:'John', last:'Smith'}));
```

[check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/qr3fX/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an HTML templating language in Javascript, you might want to look into [Mustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/).

It seems fairly popular.

Hope that helps.