# What is the preferred template library for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, templates

I'm getting to a stage where I need to build up HTML client side based on JSON responses from the server. Bugger doing this manually.

I'm already using jQuery on the app. I had a quick look for [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) but the docs tell me it's deprecated, awaiting a better plugin.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449780/recommended-javascript-html-template-library-for-jquery) asks pretty much the same thing, but the question is close to 3 years old now, I'm assuming plenty could have changed by now.

Answer (score 5):

Boris Moore, the same guy who created jQuery Templates is currently working on a project which is pretty much like jQuery-templates-in-steroids. He explains it [here](http://www.borismoore.com/2011/10/jquery-templates-and-jsviews-roadmap.html).

In short, if jQuery Templates is the best engine around, you can give [jsViews](http://borismoore.github.com/jsviews/demos/index.html) and [jsRender](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/index.html) a try.

[Here's another presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/BorisMoore/jsviews-next-generation-jquery-templates) that summarizes it all very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You may checkout [micro templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) from John Resig.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [jTemplates](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/) by many years and really like how its simple yet powerful. Unfortunatelly, it isn't updated anymore and I think its deprecated too.

Answer (score 0):

There's also Distal http://code.google.com/p/distal for inline templating.