# using templates in jQuery

Tags: jquery

i'm looking for an jquery alternative to Ext.Template.
for example.:

```
var template = new Ext.Template(
    '<div',
        '<span>{text}</span>'
    '</div>'
);
template.append('body', {text: 'my awesome template'});
```

Is there any native in jQuery, or do I have to use a plugin?
h

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449780/recommended-javascript-html-template-library-for-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery templating engines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170168/jquery-templating-engines)

Comment: that duplication is from 2008...