# Call jquery function from html for parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder is there a way to call my jquery function from my html code.

here's my code :

html side :

```
<td style="text-align:left;" align="left" >
    <div id="bulletin-timestamp" >
        doTimeStamp(${bulletinTimeStamp[status.index]})
    </div>
</td>
```

jquery side :

```
function doTimeStamp(x) {
    // do some parsing work
        return result;
}
```

I've tried

```
＜script type="text/javascript"＞doTimeStamp(${bulletinTimeStamp[status.index]})＜/script＞
```

but no effect..

Thanks!!

Comment: strange symbols `＜＞`, they are bigger than `<>` :D

Comment: what is the value of `${bulletinTimeStamp[status.index]}`?

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit from a [javascript templating library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449780/recommended-javascript-html-template-library-for-jquery)

Comment: ${bulletinTimeStamp[status.index]} is from my servlet's attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just return result. You need to add something to the DOM. In your script:

```
$('#bulletin-timestamp').text(doTimeStamp(x));
```