# Using a drop-down multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to write a `<select>` menu and use it in multiple places on web page?

example:

```
<select id="dm">
  <option value="">Select Quantity</option>
  <option value="less ">50 - 60</option>
  <option value="medium ">61 - 70</option>
  <option value="large ">71 - 80</option>
  <option value="xl ">Above 80</option>
</select>
```

How can I use this menu multiple times within the same webpage?

Comment: yes, but you can't use the same id twice on the same page.

Comment: Clone the elements with `$('#dm').clone()`. You will need to change (or remove the id attribute on the copies as id must be unique on the page)

Comment: Ctrl + C -> Ctrl + V :D If you are using JS you can look into template engine which allows you to do that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449780/recommended-javascript-html-template-library-for-jquery

Comment: Using a class instead of an ID is a really simple way of solving the multiple ID issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the original in a dummy script block as a template (text/template is not recognized so is ignored).

```
<script id="dm" type="text/template">
    <select>
       <option value="">Select Quantity</option>
       <option value="less ">50 - 60</option>
       <option value="medium ">61 - 70</option>
       <option value="large ">71 - 80</option>
       <option value="xl ">Above 80</option>
    </select>
</script>
```

Create copies using:

```
var copy = $('#dm').html();
something.append(copy);
```

This avoids the *unique id* issue (as the select has no id). It is also very easy to read/maintain.

As suggested below, if you want to use this in a form, the select must be named:

```
var $copy = $($('#dm').html()).attr('name', newMenuName);
something.append(copy);
```

*note: The extra $() converts the string to a DOM element first before adding the attribute.*

Comment: If you want to use in a form, you must provide a name to the select. Using this answer, you can do this before append: `copy.attr('name','some name');`

Comment: How do I COPY when adding the drop-down dynamically? [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9hn5Ln/2/)

Comment: @Nelie: Can you please explain what you mean? How is the dropdown being added dynamically?

Comment: See my JSFiddle. When "Add a Thought" is clicked 2 text fields appear. How do I have the drop-down next to the text field created in `#outWrap` using your COPY method?

Comment: @Nelie: Is this a separate question? That fiddle does not have a menu?

Comment: Yes I did not mention that in my question above. this is actually what I'm after... Appreciate if you could help on this matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60609/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-nelie).

Comment: Thanks TrueBlueAussie. That's exactly what I was looking for! I wish I could give you more points. :)

Comment: When you can. I have plenty of other under-appreciated answers :) Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

Give the `<select>` a class and then you can use the jQuery [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function.

```
<select class="dropClass" id="dm">
  <option value="">Select Quantity</option>
  <option value="less ">50 - 60</option>
  <option value="medium ">61 - 70</option>
  <option value="large ">71 - 80</option>
  <option value="xl ">Above 80</option>
</select>

<div id="someDiv"><!-- you want the dropdown here too --></div>
```

```
$( ".dropClass" ).clone().appendTo( "#someDiv" );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h58wajef/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Using a templating engine such as Handlebar or similar would be easy, but might be over kill in your case.

I would simply store the complete HTML code in a variable, and then inject that variable wherever I need it for future use. Problem here is complexity and maintainability of the HTML code. In any case something like this (using jQuery):

JS:

```
var myDropDown = 'youthtmlcode is here'

$("#myDropDown").html(myDropDown);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDropDown"></div>
```

Comment: HTML in strings is error prone and not easy to read/maintain. Your templating suggestion is much better.

Comment: I agree. Sometimes I use both ways, depending what I need. My opinion is that in this users case, using Handlebar might prove to be difficult. I apologize if I made mistake :)